# How to change filesystem of truecrypt volumes?

Tags: linux, filesystems, truecrypt, disk-encryption

How do I operate on these volumes? If I mount them, they are directories, if I do not mount them, they are encrypted. What about an outer partition that may be host to a hidden partition, will a change corrupt anything?

There is no data that need be kept.

Answer (score 2):

Truecrypt provides formatting options on volume creation. If there's nothing there you can just delete it and recreate it in whatever format you want.

Running `mkfs.FORMAT /dev/loop#` or `/dev/mapper/truecrypt#` will usually corrupt it, making it unmountable.

Comment: Truecrypt does not provide an option to select the filesystem for the outer volume of a hidden partition. It's always vfat. That's why I'm asking if it's changeable.